# Compare values in string array

Tags: c#, string, compare

I have a string[], that is filled with Error Messages from a log file.
Now I need to compare them to each other, because a lot of the Errors are the same.
And then I need to return them, in order to filter the whole log file with a regex.

Here's my code:

```
foreach (string item in errSplit)
{        
    string[] lines = item.Split(new string[] {"\r\n", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

    fisrt = lines.FirstOrDefault();

    // Here I woud like to loop thru the sring and compare the values
    // and save the string,so every error exists just onece
    fehler.WriteLine(fisrt);
}
```

That's how the string looks right know:

> Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System...
>   Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System...
>   Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - ~/Default...

Comment: What about `Enumerable.Distinct` ? if the *string* items exactly matches, then just return `yourArray.Distinct()` *.ToArray()*

Comment: If you use a [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead of a `string[]` it will automatically solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

If all that you want is to just create a version of your array with only one of any given entry, there's a few ways you could do that. With LINQ, this would probably be easiest:

```
IEnumerable<string> yourFilteredErrors = yourErrors.Distinct();
```

If you need an array, rather than an `IEnumerable`, just call `.ToArray()` on `yourFilteredErrors`.

Or, if you're not able to use LINQ, you can just iterate:

```
List<string> filteredErrors = new List<string>();
foreach (string error in yourErrors) {
    if (!filteredErrors.Contains(error)) {
        filteredErrors.Add(error);
    }
}
```

If efficiency is a concern, you should just replace the `List<string>` with a `HashSet<string>`.